# How to get top N business in each category in oracle sql?

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I write the following code to calculate the average rating for business, now I want the TOP 2 business in business category, I try to add `HAVING COUNT(*) <= 2`, but it doesn't work...

```
SELECT r.Bussiness_ID, b.Bussiness_Name, c.Catg_name, AVG(r.Rating) 
FROM review r,bussiness b, busn_catg c 
WHERE b.Bussiness_ID = r.Bussiness_ID 
AND b.Category = c.Catg_ID 
GROUP BY r.Bussiness_ID,b.Bussiness_Name, c.Catg_name 
ORDER BY c.Catg_name, AVG(r.Rating);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT r.Bussiness_ID, b.Bussiness_Name, c.Catg_name, AVG(r.Rating) rt FROM review r,bussiness b, busn_catg c WHERE b.Bussiness_ID = r.Bussiness_ID AND b.Category = c.Catg_ID GROUP BY r.Bussiness_ID,b.Bussiness_Name, c.Catg_name ORDER BY c.Catg_name, rt desc;
```